# Fedora 26 and 27 Backup deja-dup, Duplicity "Permission Denied"

Tags: fedora

Two machines.  Both running Fedora 27 (saw this issue on Fedora 26 as well. Thought changing to Fedora 27 would fix it.  New installs not upgrades.

Both machines run Gnome (wayland) 64 bit.  Machine 1 is the workstation and Machine 2 I am using to store the backups.

Machine 1 has sshd operational and enabled.  Machine 1 also have NFS installed and operational.  NFS is used to the file server from Machine 1.  I want too add the to the backup machine, machine 2" as soon as I have the backups running and can backup Machine 1's files to the backup machine,machine 2.
I have sshd also running on Machine 2 and can log in from machine 2 to Machine 1 
ssh machine name@192......  Then enter the password.
The "Backup" app in Fedora 27 is then opened and the files to be backed up on Machine 1 selected, rubbish is excluded.  Set the path to the backup location  using
ssh 192.......  /machine-1-backup 
Select every day.
enter a password.

Using this the initial backup worked bur subsequent backups always fail.  I get a permission denied message with no errors showing.
When the backup starts a screen come up asking for a password.  I enter it and a few seconds later a I get a "permissions Denied" message.

I have tied doing a chmod -R 777 /machine-1-backup  no difference.

I am at my wits end to know what I ave done wrong.
Any ideas please

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Deja-Dup works fine for weeks/months, but every now and then I got opaque "Permission denied" errors with zero details.
When I try via duplicity on the command line, everything works. (Check this with `duplicity list-current-files <url>`.)

The workaround described by [this blog post](https://www.stepardo.de/blog/howto-fix-deja-dup/) works for me: run the backup in a new dbus environment:

```
dbus-run-session -- deja-dup --backup
```

Note that I only need this once in a while. After a reboot dbus/deja-dup has fixed itself and I don't need this workaround anymore (until the next time when it has a hiccup).